# Designing a web service which streams stdout

Tags: logging, stream

So we have a web service which among other things, automates the running of a binary.  This binary has std:out which we would like to stream to clients in realtime.  We want this to be idempotent in the sense that if the connection drops, the client can reconnect and continue where it left off including seeing the history of what was streamed in the past.  Our web server is written in go.

What are some technologies I can leverage for something like this as I'm not entirely familiar how these sorts of systems are designed?

Off the top of my head here's what comes to my mind:

One process that writes to a file, client connects to server via sockets, and server reads from the file and pushes data to socket. Would need a marker to signify that the file is done.  Scalability wise this seems annoying as we need to manage socket connections, disk bottlenecks, etc.

Could something like kafka or kinesis be leveraged here? Maybe cloudwatch or existing logging systems?  How does github actions for example do this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a perfect use case for **Socket streaming**.
For a similar use case, we had to stream Kafka Connect logs from the workers to the custom UI that we built. This [Frontail](https://github.com/mthenw/frontail) framework written in Node JS might be a good start.

A node/go log server that streams data from sockets and writes to Kafka is all you need basically. Clients would connect to a **Log Service** (not the binary log server) that consumes messages from Kafka. Hence you do not have to maintain as many connections as there are the number of clients.

The output stream can then be written into Kafka for history and a decoupled architecture. You can store the last read timestamp per user/client into MySQL and use that as an offset to consume logs from that point.

[image]

Few more things:

- `Idempotency` is not what you've defined here in the context of a lost connection to a re connection. This is more of a **robustness** expectation.
- You've not specified how big the log file streams would be and the number of clients that'd consume from them. You've also not specified how **critical** streaming this log is. If it's mission critical, the design changes.
- Is the binary running **locally** or **remotely**. If locally, is the log produced locally or remotely?
- A service that automates a binary while tending to dispatch web requests, **is an anti pattern.** You should schedule this "job" on a cluster dedicated to scheduling such as on `Azkaban`. You'd have greater flexibility and your service gets rid of the convoluted automation.

If you choose Azkaban and configure your std out correctly, the entire job log can be fetched using an [API](https://azkaban.github.io/azkaban/docs/latest/#api-fetch-execution-job-logs)

```
GET /executor?ajax=fetchExecJobLogs&session.id={{azkabanSessionId}}&execid=<>&offset=0&length=10000&jobId=<>
```